# Bootstrap responsive layout one column offset on md

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to do something like this with bootstrap 4?

- on large screen, 3 columns of the same size:
  111 222 333
- on medium screen, 2 columns of same size with 333 under 222 :
  111 222
        333
- on small screen,
  111
  222
  333

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" style="background-color: red">111</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: blue">222</div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow">333</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it's possible. what have you tried so far?

Comment: <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" style="background-color: red">111</div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: blue">222</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow">333</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

Answer (score 1):

Just use `offset-` on the `333` column like this...

https://www.codeply.com/go/3R1l8JIWOt

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: red">111</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: blue">222</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6 col-lg-4 offset-lg-0" style="background-color: yellow">333</div>
</div>
```

This works responsively so that the offset used to push the `333` column to the right is only applied on `md` screen widths.